# Activiti assign/reassign process

Tags: activiti, business-process-management

I am a beginner on Activiti BPM. I would like to implement a ticket process flow.

Say for example:
Start event ->
Any user can create ticket. `(User task)`
This ticket will be emailed to Manager identified by ticket type. `(Service task)`
- I am using service task here instead of email task as I would be using Spring/Velocity template.
- In this email a URL similar to this will be sent along:

```
/ticket/123/assign
```

Now this ticket will be claimed by the Manager who received the email. `(User task)`
However he could decide to reassign this task to some other Manager.
This delegation process is indefinite and can be repeated any number of times by any Manager during the workflow.

How do I implement this assign and reassign process in Activiti? Is there any suitable BPMN constructs/pattern or examples on how to achieve this in Activiti? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create process definition like this:

[image]

- For sending email to manager use **TaskListener** with event type **create**. More info in http://activiti.org/userguide/#taskListeners
- If the process arrives to the **UserTask** in Activiti database is created instance of ACT_RU_TASK. There are three attributes:

  - OWNER_ user who owns the task
  - ASSIGNEE_ user who solves the task
  - DELEGATION_ delegating to another user, with keeping original assignee
    More info in http://activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnUserTask

For your purposes, you can use Owner for first manager (who is notified by email, you can set owner in TaskListener) and Assignee for assigned manager. You can change assignee any number of times you want.

Activiti engine solves only process flow not UI.